# Localstack produces empty files in docker-compose folder

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, localstack

Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```
localstack:
image: localstack/localstack:latest
container_name: test-localstack
ports:
  - '4563-4599:4563-4599'
  - '8055:8080'
networks:
  - jema_net
environment:
  - SERVICES=s3
  - DEBUG=1
  - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
  - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
  - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
  - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  - ./aws:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d
```

`docker-entrypoint-initaws.d` I use to create some buckets automatically.

I found, every time where there is request to s3 service then empty file with random name like `6f5a2d27-2746-45c3-b5b5-d949e5480ea8` created in my local `docker-compose` root folder.
How to stop it?
Many thanks!